# How to solve error Profile does not support product ads on Amazon Ads API

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I am using the Amazon Advertising API and when requesting the campaign list for either the sponsored products or sponsored brands endpoint I get

```
{"code":"400","details":"Profile does not support product ads","requestId":"23SEDRS6NYJD8EHE7CS8"}
```

I'm not really sure what is going on, for other accounts I'm not getting this error and can't seem to find information anywhere on what might be going on.

The owner of the account says he has ads on that particular account, so he has product ads in the account.

What to do?